# Make django code run after page load

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

So I would like for the python code in the web page to run once a second and update the page if the database has been changed but it only does it on page load due to how django works.

```
function refresh(){
        //Clear info boxes
        {% for TrackedObject in allTrackedObjects %}

          //Add info to boxes

        {% endfor %}

    }

window.setInterval(refresh,1000);
```

Is there a way for the call from setInterval to run the python code again as well?

Comment: You're misunderstanding how Django and Django template language works... this isn't Python either.

Comment: But is there a way to implement this sort of thing with django?

Comment: Never mind, gonna set up an API and have django initialize it but update via API calls.

Comment: You should probably read up on the fundamentals of HTTP. The only interaction your browser/javascript can have with Django is to make a request and receive a response, nothing else. Can you make a request every second? Sure, but you need to setup Django to handle that specific request and return the appropriate response, and you need to check for changes and possibly update the HTML in your javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get it done would be to have javascript on the page that either reloads the whole page or a portion of the page you want to change.   for the portion of a page code option, from the JS you would invoke a django url in your app and return either html to replace in part of the DOM or JSON that you used to replace data in your existing page.

Comment: Yeah, I did try the refresh route but it caused usability problems, I think setting up an API is the way to go for me, marked your answer correct as it would work and you may as well have the free internet points!